# Why is mb_convert_case in PHP 5.4 breaking my string, when in 5.2 it doesn't?

Tags: php, unicode

I have the following code:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str = 'áá áá';
echo $str."\n";
echo mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE)."\n";
echo bin2hex($str)."\n";
echo bin2hex(mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE))."\n";
```

Using PHP 5.2.2, I get the following output:

```
áá áá
áá áá
c3a1c3a120c3a1c3a1
c3a1c3a120c3a1c3a1
```

Using PHP 5.4.3, I get this:

```
áá áá
á� á�
c3a1c3a120c3a1c3a1
c3a1e3a120c3a1e3a1
```

My expected output in both cases would have been:

```
áá áá
Áá Áá
c3a1c3a120c3a1c3a1
c381c3a120c381c3a1
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why isn't the á being converted to Á?
2. Why is PHP 5.4 breaking my strings?

Comment: Can't specifically answer your question, but try explicitly passing the `$encoding` parameter to `mb_convert_case` as well.

Comment: I'd suggest as well what @deceze commented. add the explicit encoding parameter. also check your default encodings for mb string. which encoding is the file in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either pass in `$encoding` to every call to `mb_` functions, or set:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

to make sure PHP knows what encoding you're working with. Otherwise the encoding comes from `php.ini`, or a default ISO-8859-1 if not included there either.

So your 5.4 installation is defaulting to ISO-8859-1 and so lowercasing the lead byte of the UTF-8 sequence, breaking it. The same happens for me in 5.2, so maybe there's something else about your 5.2 installation that's different - maybe `internal_encoding` in the `ini` being set to something else without letters in those byte positions?

Comment: Ah, of course, I set HTTP encoding headers, but my internal_encoding wasn't set! According to PHP 5.2's phpinfo(), my mbstring.internal_encoding setting was ISO-8859-1,  whereas in my PHP 5.4 configuration, it's not set at all ("no value"). Interestingly though, 5.4 does seem to default to ISO-8859-1 as you suggested (a call to mb_internal_encoding() with no parameters confirms this) but the output differs between the two versions. Regardless, explicitly setting the mbstring.internal_encoding to UTF-8 solves the problem in both versions. Thanks for your help!